Remove all other materials from non-active objects after material link?
I want to know how to link materials in a way that removes all other materials from non-active objects leaving just materials that the active object has.
I want all my passive objects to only have materials that my active object has after the link. Removing all other materials that active object doesn't have.
My active object:

My passive objects: 

3 easy steps:

Select objects TO which materials should be copied
While pressing Shift click on the object FROM which materials should be copied (to make this object active)
In the active object's material tab:
Down arrow icon > Copy Material to Selected :



*Don't let the bad naming to confuse you: While named Copy MATERIAL to selected, this option copies ALL materials from the active object to selected ones.
**Plus it deletes ALL other materials (which do not match active object's materials)
